# Casio fx 991ms Factorial

Tags: statistics, factorial

I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this, but I can't find the answer through google.

I'm wondering how to find factorials on my casio f-991MS calculator. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've casio fx-991ES and it has a button for factorial. If your calculator supports factorial computation it must have a key for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh! I've found it. It's the shift of $x^-1$ for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Casio fx-991D.  Like many calculators, it has an ${}_nP_r$ key, in this case at the SHIFT of the multiplication button. One can calculate $n!$ by using ${}_nP_n$. So $n$ gets entered twice, which is not much of a nuisance.